# Laravel - execute GlobalScope orderby first - in the beginning

Tags: laravel, eloquent

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/603865fa5e7f1dedcd9e6c7095d2c8c2

Is it possible to order first by GlobalScope and after by "orderby in controller query?"

ex (gist): I would like to order first by status and after by titulo

Laravel 5.2

Comment: isn't it working with that order?

Comment: It is returning:
  select * from `produto` order by `titulo` desc, `status` desc
  
But I would like:
  select * from `produto` order by `status` desc, `titulo` desc